# label gets cropped in horizontal collection view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

So all I need is to make a horizontal list of just labels and for this I used a collection view. it looks like it works as expected but my label gets cropped and only half the label shows just like this:

[image]

and this is how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

my vc code:

```
class STViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    let data: [stmodel] = [stmodel(text: "صف أول"),
                           stmodel(text: "صف ثاني"),
                           stmodel(text: "صف ثالث")]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    

}

extension STViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! ClassesCollectionViewCell
        cell.configure(with: data[indexPath.row])
        return cell;
    }
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your problem, you can solve it by using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

```
extension STViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 70, height: 80)
    }
}
```

To learn more about UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, you can read the Apple documentation. [link]: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

Comment: Note that using `sizeForItemAt` will result in **fixed-size** cells. If the goal is **dynamic-width** cells, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to set `layout.itemSize`, and you do not need to implement `sizeForItemAt`.

In fact, if you want variable-width cells (which it looks like you want), then using either of those will not give you the desired results.

Since you are using Storyboard, make sure your collection view Estimated Cell Size is Automatic:

[image]

It can help during development to give your UI elements contrasting colors to make it easy to see the frames.

For example, my Storyboard looks like this:

[image]

So, here's how that looks at run-time...

First, with the "development" colors, plus a red-border around the collection view so we can see its frame:

[image]

Then, with "run-time" colors:

[image]

and without the red border:

[image]

To get that, I used your code...

You didn't provide your `stmodel` so I used this:

```
struct stmodel {
    var text: String = ""
}
```

and a simple cell class to try and match your images:

```
class ClassesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
    
    func configure(with: stmodel) {
        theLabel.text = with.text
        
        // un-comment these after development
        //  or set them in Storyboard
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

and the controller class - note there is no `.itemSize` or `sizeForItemAt` code:

```
class STViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    let data: [stmodel] = [stmodel(text: "صف أول"),
                           stmodel(text: "صف ثاني"),
                           stmodel(text: "صف ثالث"),
                           stmodel(text: "العنصر الرابع الأطول")
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // during development, so we can see the collection view frame
        // comment (or delete them) after development
        //collectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        //collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
    
}

extension STViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! ClassesCollectionViewCell
        cell.configure(with: data[indexPath.row])
        return cell;
    }
}
```

and here's the Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21507" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="EkW-Jg-PCP">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21505"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="xyK-2E-YPW">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="EkW-Jg-PCP" customClass="STViewController" customModule="cvtemp" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="UzK-83-pcT">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nXQ-0Y-BK6">
                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="119" width="313" height="60"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="CcK-kk-cEE"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" automaticEstimatedItemSize="YES" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="u6U-pC-5Jh">
                                    <size key="itemSize" width="128" height="40"/>
                                    <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                                </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                                <cells>
                                    <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="myCell" id="8jb-8e-kTy" customClass="ClassesCollectionViewCell" customModule="cvtemp" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="16" width="73.333333333333329" height="28.333333333333329"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                        <collectionViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="t3x-HA-Fd9">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="73.333333333333329" height="28.333333333333329"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gce-1u-VwE">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="16.000000000000004" y="4" width="41.333333333333343" height="20.333333333333332"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="gce-1u-VwE" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="Oux-2u-34y"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="gce-1u-VwE" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="t3x-HA-Fd9" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="j3p-5L-sQt"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="gce-1u-VwE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="t3x-HA-Fd9" secondAttribute="top" constant="4" id="jJk-HA-y7p"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="gce-1u-VwE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="4" id="uYo-Ae-NHe"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </collectionViewCellContentView>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="theLabel" destination="gce-1u-VwE" id="9bk-kQ-LCV"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </collectionViewCell>
                                </cells>
                            </collectionView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="yKI-9a-aDK"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.75663715600000003" green="0.88705736400000001" blue="0.9215784669" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="nXQ-0Y-BK6" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="yKI-9a-aDK" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="3Jy-g1-UwM"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nXQ-0Y-BK6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="yKI-9a-aDK" secondAttribute="top" constant="60" id="UPE-tv-i1d"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="yKI-9a-aDK" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="nXQ-0Y-BK6" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="fkt-Lq-iUy"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="collectionView" destination="nXQ-0Y-BK6" id="BFH-sB-sph"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ZoX-CK-vDN" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="351.90839694656489" y="106.33802816901409"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and found 2 effective way to solve that.

**1.** You can create a new instance of **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** and set that as the **collectionViewLayout** of your **UICollectionView**. By doing this, you can easily control the **itemSize** of your **UICollectionView** so that it doesn't get cropped. To achieve this, edit your **viewDidLoad()** in the following way.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize  = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }
```

**2.** You can use the **sizeForItemAt** method of **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** protocol. This will also allow you to set the size for the item of **UICollectionView**. Just by simply adding the following extension you can achieve that.

```
    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
        }
    }
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Note that using `.itemSize` or `sizeForItemAt` will result in **fixed-size** cells. If the goal is **dynamic-width** cells, that won't work.